# Load pages in background with Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, userscripts

I'd like to be able to make the browser load a bunch of web pages in the background each time I launch Chrome. This way, once I click on one of them, it displays right away.

The best would be to get that page kept always refreshed in the background, but that is more optional.

Any idea of extension or usercript I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know of a sane way to do what you ask - though maybe a caching proxy, such as squid would in effect appease your needs?

Answer (score 1):

It's built in by default:

Spanner > Options > Basics > On Startup > Open the following pages

Comment: That's extremely nice! - I suppose my caching answer may still be worthy of consideration, but this seems like exactly what the literal question is calling for. +1 from me indeed.

Comment: Maybe try these: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ofojbjgaaddibdfpmmjeonahgbacejid & https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oilipfekkmncanaajkapbpancpelijih